# Extracting text files from a ZIP File

Tags: python

Using Python, I am trying to extract text files from a specific ZIP file, using the zipfile module.

When I try to extract all of the text files using the "extractall()" function, the text files become folders when they are extracted.

Here is my code:

```
import zipfile


new_zip = zipfile.ZipFile("NewZip.zip", "w")

new_zip.write("Hello.txt")

new_zip.extractall()
```

Can anyone tell me why the "Hello.txt" file, when extracted, becomes a folder rather than a text file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the folder structure like `NewZip.zip` ? Is it  `NewZip.zip>Hello.txt` or  `NewZip.zip>Hello.txt>Hello.txt`

Comment: As far as I was working with it, I was just wanting to create a blank ZIP file as "NewZip.zip", and add an existing ".txt" file to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the new archive, to update its content:

```
new_zip = zipfile.ZipFile("NewZip.zip", "w")
new_zip.write("Hello.txt")
new_zip.close()
new_zip = zipfile.ZipFile("NewZip.zip", "r")
new_zip.extractall()
```